# Using JQuery, how can I convert a comma separated list of image URLs to an distinct image tags?

Tags: jquery, string, csv

I have a comma separated list of image URL's, each of which I need to wrap in an img tag in order to display them.

Eg

With jquery, how could I convert this...

```
<div class="pics">http://example.com/a.jpg, http://example.com/b.jpg, http://example.com/c.jpg</div>
```

Into this

```
<div class="pics"><img src="http://example.com/a.jpg"><img src="http://example.com/b.jpg"><img src="http://example.com/c.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong - and in what way - with your own code? Incidentally, since you edited your question there's no obvious difference between the beginning code and the expected output (except that it's a little messier and harder to read). Show the ([mcve]) HTML of the 'input' and the 'output'.

Comment: I don't know where to start with it. I edited my question in order to format the code properly, since when I posted it on my phone, the urls converted into actual clickable urls, which was not intended.

Comment: The beginning code is a printed string of the URLs. The images themselves do not get displayed. So in essence, I'd like to remove the comma's and wrap/embed the URL inside an img tag. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Jamiec for correcting the formatting in my original post.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to show at least some attempt so we know what understanding of the language you currently have is.  At the moment your questyion is too broad and therefore off topic.  Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to [get the contents of the original div](https://api.jquery.com/html/), split the string (vanilla javascript) and then again use jQuery to [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) the div and [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) img tags

```js
var images = $('.pics').html().split(', ');
$('.pics').empty().append(images.map(i => `<img src="${i}">`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pics">http://example.com/a.jpg, http://example.com/b.jpg, http://example.com/c.jpg</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery solution might be helpful..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Get String Value
 var pics_str = $('.pics').text();

 // Split String using ',' (comma) and store as an Array
 var pics_arr = pics_str.split(',');

 // Reset String Value to blank
 pics_str = '';

 // Converting Each Array value to IMG tag
 $.each(pics_arr, function(index, el) {

  // Remove white space from string
  imgPath = this.trim();

  // Assign image path to IMG tag
  pics_str = pics_str + '<img src="'+imgPath+'" alt="">';
 });

 // Adding Full IMG tags string into selector
 $('.pics').html(pics_str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pics">https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/196862813/w%3D440_h%3D440/29f82cfcce960b615b75e961e7b9fc16?v=0, https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_8vRM6cq8Q9LvN2Oe3sZG_457PQgTvBhC4kjOZb4FpTC5iBr1, https://www.producerspot.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Touch-Loops-VHS-Rhythms-Sample-Pack-400x400.jpg</div>
```